# Sort JSON Array in UIPickerView by parent tag

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, conditional-statements

I download a list of sports teams. The contents of the JSON list must then be presented in a `UIPickerView`. Here is the contents of the JSON;

```
{
 success: "true",
 message: [
{
 category_id: 21,
 category_name: "MAN UTD",
 parent: "EPL"
},
{
 category_id: 22,
 category_name: "Liverpool",
 parent: "EPL"
},
{
 category_id: 27,
 category_name: "Real Madrid",
 parent: "La Liga"
},
{
 category_id: 75,
 category_name: "Barcelona",
 parent: "La Liga"
},
{
 category_id: 23,
 category_name: "Valencia",
 parent: "La Liga"
},
{
 category_id: 24,
 category_name: "Bayern Munich",
 parent: "Bundesliga"
}
]
}
```

I know how to parse the JSON, but I need to present the `UIPickerView` with the parent above the associated teams.
So I need to add them to an array like so;

EPL,
Man Utd,
Liverpool,
La Liga,
Real Madrid,
Barcelona,
Valencia,
Bundesliga,
Bayern Munich.

Is there a clean way to do this in a conditional statement? I need to be able to sort them like above, but it would be great if it could handle dynamic content incase the list gets added to etc.

Comment: show the full response data, bz it is easy for optimize the work

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok, please see above

Comment: [self.arrNames sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];;
above method is for arrange mutable values in ascending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// First Store Json Data in To NSArray       

 // NSSortDescriptor (better)

  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
  sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"parent"
                                              ascending:YES];
  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
  NSArray *sortedArray;
  sortedArray = [drinkDetails sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Very good, but how would I add the parent name to the list before its children, like in the question.